# Android Set Scrollview dynamically on wrap height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm working in a view that has a description meta data at the bottom. Trying to show an extra caption Text View inside when a case happens in the code side, so this text view could be or not displayed. But, if I do that the height in my Linear Layout (The blue one) gonna be increase, and this is actually what I'm wanted to avoid.

How can I keep the same height that the linear Layout has before the caption Text View appears, since all the heights are as WRAP_CONTENT?

This is how my Layout looks like so far:

```
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pp_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_normal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Desc 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="desc 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Desc 3"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/extra_caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Extra Caption"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that a Scroll view gonna be required for sure, but I wanted use the scroll view when the extra caption (text view) has visibility as VISIBLE, otherwise I don't wanted to use the scroll view.

I tried to do this without success so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pp_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_normal">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Desc 1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="desc 2"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Desc 3"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/extra_caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Extra Caption"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In other words I'm trying to do this:

[image]

Comment: why the second layout you posted didn't work? what was wrong with that? You will always have to use ScrollView because there are different screen sizes and you should have scroll if views don't fit, for example in landscape view nothing will fit without scroll.

Comment: The thing is, since I'm no defining a height fro every TextView, the LinearLayout that wrap these (The blue one) does not keep the same height, instead of that it is increasing it. So my goal is, keep the same height

Comment: Then give blue part fixed height and put a ScrollView inside only blue area.

Answer (score 0):

Going this way, it worked!
The key was setting an Id to the ScrollView, this way I could modify the height programmatically:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        ...

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/my_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

To get the layout params:

```
  private void displayExtraCaption() {
            extraCaptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            int scrollHeightBeforeCaption = myScrollView.getHeight();
           ...
           }
```

Here it comes another challenge, because I'm implementing this on a Fragment which is inside of a Lib, so I have no access to the activities(The Lib has only Fragments), so the first time that I'm calling this method scrollHeightBeforeCaption is equals 0 in order to avoid that I set a Runnable if this happens:

```
 private void displayExtraCaption() {
            extraCaptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            int scrollHeightBeforeCaption = myScrollView.getHeight();
            if (scrollHeightBeforeCaption == 0) {
                myScrollView
                        .post(new Runnable() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      refreshMetaDataScrollViewHeight();
                                  }
                              }
                        );
            } else {
                refreshMetaDataScrollViewHeight();
            }
}
```

And finally my refreshMetaDataScrollViewHeight() is the one who keep the original height in the ScrollView once my extra caption label goes to VISIBLE:

```
private void refreshMetaDataScrollViewHeight() {
    int scrollHeightBeforeCaption = metadataScrollView.getHeight();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams myScrollViewParams = myScrollView.getLayoutParams();
    myScrollViewParams.height = scrollHeightBeforeCaption;
    myScrollView.setLayoutParams(myScrollViewParams);

    myScrollView.invalidate();
    extraCaptionTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    extraCaptionTextView.invalidate();
}
```

Thanks for your time to read this :)